# Can a binary file read and writen by StreamReader and StreamWriter be fixed?

Tags: c#, .net

If I read and wrote a binary file using StreamReader and StreamWriter, can the file be repaired?

```
// Original Code - Corrupted the Destination File
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destinationFileName, false))
        {
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}


// New Code - Destination File is Good
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(destinationFileName))
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(fs);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I read and wrote a binary file using StreamReader and StreamWriter, can the file be repaired?

It depends what's in the file. If it's *actually* text in the right encoding, then you won't have lost anything.

If it's genuinely binary data (e.g. a JPEG) then you'll *almost certainly* have lost information, irreparably. Just don't do it, and if you've already done it, I probably wouldn't try to "fix" the files - I'd write them off as "bad".

If you'd used ISO-8859-1, it's possible that all would have been well - although it would still have been bad code which would be better off changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read it with a StreamReader and see if the string you get back makes sense. This is your best option to recover the data. Once you have a "correct" string you need to try different Encodings to write to a binary file. Try UTF8, UTF16 and Encoding.Default.

I guess it will take a bit of playing around to recover some of the data. Please note that it is likely that you have lost some of it permanently.